# The Walking Dead cricket noise?

Tags: the-walking-dead, zombie

In The Walking Dead TV show, I noticed that every time there is a cricket noise that gets louder. Walkers are almost always nearby. Can somebody confirm or deny this? Is it related to anything?

Answer (score 24):

The Walking Dead is shot in Georgia, in different towns according to the season. That cricket noise you are hearing is being generated by cicada. It's almost impossible to scrub from outdoor shots due to the large amount of frequencies the sound covers. As the first three seasons were shot in the summer when the cicada are at their peak. Here's a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwlmHvYIbQA) that can show you how loud they they are and how sustained it is.

The reason that it seems to get more prevalent is the lack of back ground noise for it to contrast with. The Walking Dead often has the music and other sound effects go quiet for the scare value. That means that the normal background noise surges to the forefront.

Comment: Man...cicadas are annoying when they're in season. Don't they come out once every 13 or 17 years or something like that? They come out in DROVES though when they're around. According to Wikipedia it's a technique called predatory satiation. Basically, there are so many, the birds are too full to eat them all.

Comment: @MikeBrown In some parts of the country, they live for 17 years. They only swarm every so often, but down south they are constant during the summer.

Comment: That, my friend, is what hot and humid sounds like.

Comment: I grew up in an Atlanta suburb that bordered some more rural area, there was definitely a lot of insect noise.  You naturally tune it out, but it can be oddly comforting or disturbing.   That region gets a lot of rain and sunshine, which I think plants and insects love.

Comment: A friend of mine hosted someone from overseas for a while who had never heard of cicadas before. The "screaming trees" really creeped him out ;-)

Comment: I thought it was normal for shows to re-record the sound for outdoor scenes. Is there a reason that Walking Dead doesn't do this?

Comment: I think sound re-recording is something that happens more in movies than tv shows on a tight schedule. In episodes of TWD (and lots of other shows) you'll often hear the background noise increase dramatically as characters speak. This is because the volume is dropped in the gaps between speech to cover up loud background noise, but obviously you need to hear dialogue. I find this very irritating, once you've heard it in a scene you can't *stop* hearing it

Comment: I'm from Texas and we get our share of Cicada's and personally I love the sound it's comforting to me and is one of natures alarm systems if something gets to close to them they stop letting you know something is near by , And they take 13 years to mature before they emerge from the ground crawl up the side of a tree and hatch so yes you have a new batch every year. I just wished I could find a CD with them on it I would go to sleep every night to the sound of Cicada's.

Comment: @MikeBrown - A given generation of cicadas will come out of hibernation (or the larval stage or whatever it is) a specific number of years after it is born, but a new generation is born each year, so they are always around.  Some generations are ridiculously large, so some years are worse than others.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the wave effect of the ambient sound is to do with the network processing the sound before broadcast, probably to compensate for the ridiculous sound found in most commercials. It will be a combination of compression and expansion on the original audio track. I would wager the DVD sound will be substantially better, or even if viewed on a different network.

Comment: It's not clear to me how this answers the question. Please try to make it more obvious to us dumb folks. I haven't watched Walking Dead in awhile, and I'm not familiar with the cricket noise, I assumed it was a literal cricket chirp. If it is an audio artifact, or even just used to cover up the transition from commercials, please say so more plainly.

Comment: Can you give us some references to back this up?